# jquery select change event when get selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to redirect on a specific url when user select an option

here is the code i am using

```
<select class="input-block-level" id="maqui" name="maqui">
                <option value="tela">Maquilero</option>
                <option value="textil">textil</option>
                <option value="tipo">tipo</option>
                    </select>
```

and the script

```
 $('#maqui').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    top.location.href="/ver/"+valueSelected;
});
```

I want to redirect to /ver/valueSelected

Comment: what is problem code seems fine??

Comment: the code dont redirect http://jsfiddle.net/3ppar8ms/2/

Comment: use `window.location.href` instead of `top.location.href` and if you using ifram then use `parent.location.href`, this should be work

Comment: thanks i solved the problem i forgot something very important: $(document).ready(function(){ });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<select class="input-block-level" id="maqui" name="maqui" autocomplete="off">
                <option selected disabled>Please select an option</option>
                <option value="tela">Maquilero</option>
                <option value="textil">textil</option>
                <option value="tipo">tipo</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$('#maqui').on('change', function (e) {
    window.location.href = "/ver/"+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
});
```

There are a few fallacies that you should be aware of, when using this method:

1. The event will only trigger **onChange**. Hence, the default disabled option in the select menu.
2. If the browser remembers his choice, the user won't trigger the **onChange** event if he wants to select his previous choice. Hence the `autocomplete="off"`

Comment: thanks i solved the problem i forgot something very important: $(document).ready(function(){ });